# Display week number of each month instead of days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, gantt-chart

I am preparing a tracker to list week number of each month. But, I could only get the weeks with days.

I have something like this.

[image]

And I want to change to this so the section automatically update the chart based on start and end date

[image]

Comment: So have you tried conditional formatting/ Also, many Gantt chart templates already exist, may be worth checking how they work.

Comment: @SolarMike - I checked for templates and made lot of corrections in formula, but still couldn't get it

Answer (score 1):

The conditional formatting stays the same as what Dominique has

[image]

As for the dates (note that my regional settings are different), you could use the following if you want to base it on the other sheet you have.
If your regional settings use ";" instead of ",", please edit it for your need (I figured most users use "," so I changed it to that)

> =FILTER(Sheet1!D2:PU2,Sheet1!D2:PU2)

Or have in C1 your start-date (the first visible one in your first image) and in E1; it checks if the start-date is the beginning of a week and goes to the next possible start of the week if not:

> =LET(start,C1,wday, WEEKDAY(start,2),IF(wday>1,start+7-wday+1,start))

If you want the start of the week where the Start-date falls in use:

> =LET(start,C1,wday, WEEKDAY(start,2),IF(wday>1,start-wday+1,start))

and then F1 (and as far as you want it):

> =E1+7

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably looking for a way to colour your bars if the date correspond with the start and end dates.
For that, I have created the following Excel sheet:

[image: Excel screenshot]

The colours are created, using conditional formatting.
The corresponding formula is the following:

```
=AND($A3<=C$1;C$1<=$B3)
```

Have fun :-)

P.s.: the formula in the cells is just for demonstration purposes, you can omit the formula in the cells and just put it in the conditional formatting definition.

Comment: This has everyday in the sheet. I only want to display the start date of the week. For ex: Oct Month should have only five rows, i.e: Oct 2, Oct 9,  Oct 16, Oct 23, Oct 30